# Why do resume suspended workflow in AppFabric give errors?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4, appfabric

I'm running a couple of WF 4 services with Windows Server AppFabric. Sometimes an unhandled exception occurs in a workflow and it gets abandonded (if action on unhandled exception is set to "abandon"), or suspended (if action is set to "abandon and suspend").

In the case of "abandon", the workflow is still "Running (active)" after the exception, and I expect AppFabric WorkflowManagementService to automatically continue the workflow from its last persisted point.

In the case of "abandon and suspend", I excpet to be able to manually resume the workflow via the AppFabric Dashboard.

In either case, this does not happen, but I get various error and warning messages in AppFabric Dashboard and Windows Event Viewer (Windows -> Application Server-System Services -> Admin):

Error:

> Failed to invoke service management endpoint at 'net.pipe://jon-hp/Afis.Workflow/ServiceManagement.svc' to activate service '/Afis.Workflow/ATP.xamlx'.\rException: 'The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.'

Error:

> Failed to Resume instance d626005a-63bd-4ab1-8192-62616755015c via control endpoint net.pipe://jon-hp/Afis.Workflow/ATP.xamlx/System.ServiceModel.Activities_IWorkflowInstanceManagement.\rException: System.TimeoutException: The open operation did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:01:00. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>   Inner Exception:
>   System.TimeoutException: The pipe connection was aborted because an asynchronous read from the pipe did not complete within the allotted timeout of 00:00:59.9989999. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.
>   Inner Exception:
>   System.IO.PipeException: The operation cannot be completed because the pipe was closed.  This may have been caused by the application on the other end of the pipe exiting..

Warning (periodically every 20 minutes)

> WMS was not able to activate any of the hosts - backing off. Store name 'defaultSqlPersistenceStore' ('Root).

Net.pipe is enabled for my web site and applications, and I can see the management endpoints listed in IIS Manager -> Endpoints -> Remove filter (System.ServiceModel.Activities.IWorkflowInstanceManagement).

My application endpoints are running net.tcp with transport security and Windows authentication.

This thread seems to be related, but I didn't manage to solve my problem from it:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/dublin/thread/e1705e89-34cc-4526-b11e-9d67d66c403d

EDIT 1: My scenario involves a client calling workflow A, which does some processing, then persists and returns. Workflow A then calls workflow B, and workflow B immediately throws an exception. Workflow A does not catch this, and is abandoned, but still Running (Active) from its last persistence point. Workflow B is also abandoned but has not been persisted, so gets status Running (Idle), waiting from message from workflow A.

I then expect workflow A to resume automatically and call workflow B again, but this does not happen.

EDIT 2: The types of errors I get in the Event Log don't seem consistent. In periods, I don't get any errors, but I've also seen to following (in addition to the those above):

`Failed to Resume instance 032274d1-b6e6-4163-a33a-73bffc8da2cc via control endpoint net.pipe://jon-hp/Afis.Workflow/ATP.xamlx/System.ServiceModel.Activities_IWorkflowInstanceManagement.\rException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because the instance '032274d1-b6e6-4163-a33a-73bffc8da2cc' has not yet been persisted to the instance store..`

`Failed to Resume instance d2b19a41-985e-4dc4-8fd1-955df2cde243 via control endpoint net.pipe://jon-hp/Afis.Workflow/Import.xamlx/System.ServiceModel.Activities_IWorkflowInstanceManagement.\rException: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The execution of the InstancePersistenceCommand named {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:System.Activities.Persistence/command}LoadWorkflow was interrupted by an error..`

`Failed to invoke service management endpoint at 'net.pipe://jon-hp/Afis.Workflow/ServiceManagement.svc' to activate service '/Afis.Workflow/ATP.xamlx'.\rException: 'There was an error reading from the pipe: Unrecognized error 109 (0x6d).'`

Answer (score 0):

Did yo by any change make changes to the workflow definition? If so WF4 is not able to handle that, the capability will be added to WF4.5.

Also I would enable WCF tracing on the server to see if you get any more details. Quite often the real original exception is logged but not propagated to the client.

Comment: I did not make any changes to the workflow. There's no real client involved here - it's a long running workflow with services calling each other. Will try WCF tracing.

Comment: Strange. I try suspending all workflows by setting the suspende column in the database. Next try restarting the application pool to see if there are any problems. If not, use the browser to hit the WSDL page for the workflow. That way the WorklfowServiceHost is up and running but you should have 0 workflow instances active. If that still works, try to resume one workflow at the time and see which one causes the problem.

Comment: I've run the application on two other computers now, and everything works well on them. Maybe there's some config issue I don't see...

Comment: There could be a security issue as well.